# Find the number of bijective function such that $f(3) \geq f(9) \geq \ldots \geq f(99)$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

For a function $f:\{1,3,5,7,\ldots,99\} \to \{2,4,6,8,\ldots,100\}$. Find the no of bijective functions such that $f(3) \geq f(9) \geq \ldots \geq f(99)$ is:
The sequence has a gap of $6$. So, it is like $3,9,15,21,27,\ldots$ up to $ 99$.

- How I am trying to solve and understand the question

1. As per law of finding number of bijective functions:
   If $n(a) = n(b)$. Then, number of possible bijective functions $= m!$

Here, $n$ is a function name, $m$ is total number of elements in the sets $A$, $B$.

2. What does it mean? It means that for every $1$ element of set $A$, $1$ element of set $B$ is possible. Now, using formula what we mean in basic term is:
   $f(1) = 2,4,\ldots,100$ ($50$ ways). Now, $f(3)$ will be $= 4,6,8,\ldots,100$.
3. Now coming to the question: They say
   $f(3) \geq f(9) \geq \ldots \geq f(99)$.
   As I think this means: The value you find in $f(3)$ has to be greater or equal to the value I find in $f(9)$ but I don’t know the condition for $f(5)$, $f(7)$.

I am unable to think how to solve this to get that condition of $f(3)$ and neither getting what to do $f(5)$, $f(7)$.

Comment: It's not clear what the "..." stands for. How do we complete the sequence $3,9,...,99$?

Comment: @Karl it means 15 , 21 , 27. Gap of 6 numbers

Comment: The first sentence does not make sense.

Comment: @Gary Done. Pls check now

Comment: Ok. Also please learn MathJax.

Comment: **Hint.** Suppose you decide what you want all of the $f(n)$ to be for $n \not= 6k+3$. Then the values for $n = 6k+3$ are automatically determined. ¶ Also, note that we're counting bijections, so the $\geq$ might as well be $>$.

Comment: @BrianTung I’m sorry but i didn’t understand what u mean.

Comment: @BrianTung is 6k + 3 the difference gap of f(3) , f(9) , f(15) ? If so , shouldn’t it be  3k+3 or 6k+0 ?

Comment: **Example.** Suppose you assign the even numbers from $2$ through $66$ to $f(1), f(5), f(7), f(11), f(13), f(17), \ldots$. That leaves the even numbers from $68$ through $100$ for $f(5), f(11), f(17), \ldots$, and as a result, you know that $f(5)$ must get the largest of these (i.e., $100$), $f(11)$ must get the second largest (i.e., $98$), etc. All of those are then determined. You can assign values however you like to $f(n)$ for $n \not= 6k+3$, but once you do so, you have no freedom for the remaining values, right?

Comment: @BrianTung Ohk. I am getting what u mean. I have a Q: Why did u not write f(3) , f(9). They are odd numbers as well. 2) What i have understood from what u meant to say is that: We will assume f(3) = 100 , f(9) = 98. Total ways to assign these values = 33. According to question , they say greater than or equal to. The , should we say total ways become 66 ?

Comment: Well, because $6k+3$ is a good shorthand to write the sequence $3, 9, 15, 21, \ldots$. I don't wish to be uncharitable, but a moment's substitution shows those to be the same. (And, to be honest, I tend to bristle when someone who's asking for help uses text-speak (e.g., 'u', 'pls') on Math.SE. It's symptomatic of someone who doesn't respect the people they're talking to.)

Comment: @BrianTung Im sorry. I just use “u” to write faster. It has become a habit. Ill try not to

Comment: @BrianTung What is k? If i put k = 1,2,3. I get 9 , 15 , 21. We missed 3 here. Also , i get what you meant. I think it is better to write 6k-3. For k = 1,2,3. We get 3,9,15,21..etc

Comment: I include $0$ in the natural numbers. But I figured that was close enough that you should be able to figure out what I was talking about. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @BrianTung Am I correct with where i said 66 ways ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $B = \{2,4,6,8,\ldots,100\}$, $n=|B|$,  $k = |\{3,9,15, ... 99\}|$.

1. Choose a subset of $B$ of size $k$.
2. Assign values from that subset to $f(3), f(9), f(15), ... f(99)$, such that condition $f(3) > f(9) > ... > f(99)$ holds.
3. Take the remaining elements of $B$ (there are $n-k$ of them) and assign them to $f(1), f(5), f(7), f(11),... f(97)$ in any order.

With different choices in steps 1, 2, 3 this algorithm never produces the same bijection. Also this algorithm can produce any bijection (prove it).

How many ways to do step (1)? How many ways ways to do step (2)? How many ways to do step (3)? Multiply these three numbers, and that will be the number of bijections.

Comment: For 2nd = 33. We consider f(3) = 100 , f(9) = (98) etc. For 3rd = 66!. Is it correct ?

Comment: No. How do you get 33? For 3rd it is a factorial, but not of 66. Just in case: $k=17$, $n=50$.

Comment: Ohk. I assumed to assign the greatest value to f(3) , f(9) etc. Total of these are 17 numbers. So , total will be = 17. Sorry , silly mistake i did earlier. For step 2 , it will be 50!

Comment: In 2nd step there's only one way to make the assignment.

Comment: For 2nd step , Numbers which did not come in the condition are f(1,5,7,11,13). Total odd numbers = 50. Total numbers which have condition on them = 17. Total which does not have condition on them = 33.

Comment: Is this correct sir ? Im sorry im having difficulty

Comment: We should write is 33! Because for numbers from f(3) to f(9) till f(99). These are total 17. So , we reduce the largest 17 numbers in even order from last. We get left with 2,4…66 . 0 is not included. We are left with 33 numbers. When we say f(1). It can have any number from 2 to 66. Therefore , 33 ways. Total = 33!

Comment: Is this correct ?

Comment: But $f(3)$ doesn't have to be larger  than, for example, $f(1)$ or $f(5)$. For example it could be that $f(99) = 2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138253/discussion-between-d-dmitriy-and-s-m-t).

Comment: Yes , it can be. We also dont know at what place what value will come. We have just find is the total possible no of bijections. Possible. So , since there was condition on f(3) to f(99). I assumed them to have the largest value. For the other numbers , there is no condition. So , we can assume them to be rest of even numbers left.